# MS Access Lookup Populate

Tags: ms-access, lookup

I have recently started managing an Access DB used for reporting.  Currently a single row has a 'status' that can be one of many options selected by a dropdown field.  When reporting, each of these ~15 statuses rolls up to one of 5 'rollup statuses' which is currently translated via an Excel interface.  I would like to add a column to the database table that automatically populates the correct 'rollup status' based on the selected 'status'.  I do not know if this is a calculated field, a lookup, etc. as I have very minimal Access knowledge.

For example:

```
[Status]---->[Rollup Status]
To Be Scheduled----> Planning
TBD---->Planning
Scheduled---->Scheduled
DMM Pending---->Scheduled
EEP Created---->Scheduled
Cleanup Pending---->Complete
Complete---->Complete
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you need/want a new column in your existing table?  In order to ensure data consistency, you would have to make sure to update `[Rollup Status]` every time a stored `[Status]` value gets changed. Instead of adding a new column to your table, this kind of thing can be handled with a query which joins the current table to a new table which maps `[Status]` to `[Rollup Status]`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly perhaps this would work...

In design mode: Add the new column to your table (which i will call 'total') where you want the 'rollup statuses' and call it something like  'rollup_status'

In SQL Query mode:

```
UPDATE total
  SET rollup_status = '1'
WHERE [status] = '2';
```